# Новогодний алгоритм 2019

Tags: поддержка, соревнование

Думаю, никто из участников Stack Overflow на русском уже не может себе представить Новый год без [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)’а! Предлагаю всем нам в очередной раз насладиться участием в новогоднем конкурсе на лучшие вопросы и ответы по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)!

Правила просты – необходимо задавать вопросы с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) и отвечать на них.

#### Условия подробно

В игре участвуют все вопросы, заданные с 1–го по 31–е января 2019 года с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc), а также ответы, данные за аналогичный период на вопросы по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)<sup>*</sup>.

*<sub>Учитывается время создания конкретного сообщения: если соответствующий критериям ответ будет опубликован на ранее заданный вопрос, он также будет учитываться при подсчете результатов.</sub>

#### Победители

Победителем будет считаться:

1. Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.
2. Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.
3. Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу.
4. Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.
5. Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов.
6. Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров.
7. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов.
8. Автор наибольшего количества ответов.

Среди всех сообщений, удовлетворяющих условию, выбирается одно — с наибольшим рейтингом или опубликованное ранее. «Зимние игры» пройдут в две сессии.

- *Первая сессия*: с 1–го января по 10–е января.
- *Вторая сессия*: с 11–го января по 31–е января.

В каждой сессии будут свои победители, но один приз вручается в одни руки. Таким образом, если вы станете лучшим в одной категории несколько раз или лучшим в нескольких категориях в одной сессии, приз будет все равно один.

#### Призы

Истинным призом, конечно же, являются знания, и только ради них уже стоит принимать участие! В дополнение к знаниям и хорошему настроению победители получат на выбор футболки, блокноты, наклейки, термокружки или другие памятные призы!

Знаете того, кто может задать отличный вопрос по алгоритмам? Пожалуйста, предложите ему/ей принять участие!

С нетерпением ждем ваших вопросов с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) (не забудьте подписаться на нее, чтобы не пропустить новые вопросы)!

**Важно**: Подсчет результатов будет осуществляться по прошествии 10 дней с момента окончания соревновательной сессии, чтобы уровнять шансы получения голосов.

---

#### Запросы на выявление победителей

Победители будут определяться с помощью SQL–запросов на [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Примеры запросов для выявления победителей.

1. Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
2. Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
3. Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу (находит ответы на свои вопросы).

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.OwnerUserId = parent.OwnerUserId AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
4. Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.Id = parent.AcceptedAnswerId AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
5. Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.AnswerCount, p.Score  
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.AnswerCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
6. Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, m.ViewCount, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
     Join PostMetadata m on m.PostId = p.Id
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY m.ViewCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
7. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT (DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```
8. Автор наибольшего количества ответов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT(DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```

Comment: а по какому времени ?

Comment: @Grundy По UTC.

Comment: Может стоит добавть к 7 и 8 "с положительным рейтингом"?

Comment: @talex Большое спасибо! Отличное предложение. Когда буду делать выборку, посмотрю на результаты с/без удаленных и с положительным рейтингом. Ранее, на сколько помню, результаты были одни и те же.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да, скорее всего будут одинаковые, но я параноик и ищу дыры везде :)

Comment: но это не вопрос же, хмммм....

Answer (score 3):

## Результаты первой сессии Новогоднего алгоритма 2019

От лица сообщества поздравляю победителей первой сессии. Большое спасибо всем, кто принял участие!

В этом году победителями стали:

#### Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.

[@witaway](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/225425/witaway) с вопросом «[Бинарный поиск по монотонной функции стандартными средствами C++ - возможен ли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/929091/6)», который получил два ответа и 5 голосов за.

#### Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом, принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом и наибольшего числа ответов

[@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/930488/6) в вопросе «[Как по заданному числу определить его 2-простоту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/930459/6)». Ответ был отмечен верным и получил 7 голосов за, что является лучшим рейтингом среди всех принятых ответов по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) за время первой сессии конкурса.

За первую сессию [@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) ответил на 10 вопросов с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc). Это лучший показатель по количеству ответов!

#### Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов и просмотров. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов

[@Max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218032/max) с вопросом «[Как найти число, которое встречается во всех строках матрицы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/928395/6)», который получил 3 ответа. Этот же вопрос набрал наибольшее количество просмотров среди всех вопросов по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) за время первой сессии конкурса.

За время первой сессии [@Max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218032/max) задал два вопроса по конкурсной метке, что сделало его лидером по количеству вопросов.

---

Вторая сессия в самом разгаре! У вас все еще есть возможность стать одним из победителей второй сессии Новогоднего алгоритма 2019 — задавайте интересные вопросы с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc), публикуйте ответы!

Answer (score 3):

### Результаты второй сессии Новогоднего алгоритма 2019

От лица сообщества поздравляю победителей второй сессии. Большое спасибо всем, кто принял участие!

#### Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом и наибольшим количеством просмотров

[@Max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218032/max) с вопросом «[Из цифр двух натуральных чисел создать наименьшее возможное число, сохраняя порядок следования цифр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/932622/6)», который набрал 7 голосов за, 2 ответа и 123 просмотра.

#### Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом

[@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor) c [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/932623/6) на вопрос «[Из цифр двух натуральных чисел создать наименьшее возможное число, сохраняя порядок следования цифр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/932622/6)», который набрал 10 голосов за.

#### Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу

[@witaway](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/225425/witaway) с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/931131/6) на свой вопрос «[Поиск наибольшего общего префикса двух строк бинарным поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/931119/6)». Ответ набрал два голоса за, вопрос — три.

#### Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом

[@MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo) с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/936747/6) в вопросе «[Ускорить алгоритм нахождения для каждого числа ближайшего большего правого соседа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936725/6)». Вопрос набрал два голоса за, ответ — девять.

#### Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов

[@Max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218032/max) с вопросом «[Как оптимизировать рекурсию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936847/6)», к которому быо опубликовано четыре ответа.

#### Автор наибольшего количества вопросов

[@Max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218032/max) задал 9 вопросов с суммарным рейтингом 11.

#### Автор наибольшего количества ответов

[@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) опубликовал 12 овтетов, 9 из них были приняты, с суммарным рейтингом +33.