# Сообщество уже больше полугода поддерживает откровенный оффтопик. Доколе?

Tags: дефект, закрытие-вопросов, тематика

Есть вопросы со слишком общей формулировкой:

- [Новогодний конкурс 2021 года](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1225740)
- <s>[Как нарисовать и анимировать символ (знак) российского рубля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113095)</s> (исправлен, см. историю правок)
- <s>[Как анимировать слово StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105132)</s> (исправлен, см. историю правок)
- [Новогодний конкурс 2020 года](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061127)
- [Анимация новогодней ёлочки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924210)

Все они предлагают сделать любую анимацию фактически без ограничений (кроме условного соответствия тематике), оттого являются слишком общими и должны быть закрыты согласно правилам сайта. А конкурс-2021 предлагает сделать даже не анимацию, а вообще что угодно...

Некоторые утверждают, что вопросы–соревнования у нас в рамках правил сайта. Это действительно так, и **я не имею ничего против соревнований** и никогда не высказывался против них. Однако, подчеркну жирным шрифтом:

## Такие вопросы — не соревнования!

Соревнования обязаны иметь **чёткую задачу** и **критерии победы**. Все три вопроса задают лишь поверхностную тематику (анимированный знак рубля, анимированное слово, новый год и новый год соответственно), но **чёткой задачи в них нет** (как было в старой версии одного из вопросов, «**абсолютно любые эффекты** анимации без ограничений» — это даже ещё более нагло, чем в новогодних псевдоконкурсах). Критерии победы тоже отсутствуют, хотя справка «большого» код-гольфа [требует](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) их наличия, и к нам это тоже должно относиться.

Все эти вопросы имеют формат вида «сделайте какую-нибудь анимацию», но полный ответ по созданию анимаций займёт несколько книг по css/svg/js/webgl. При этом цитирую [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> Следует задавать исключительно **практические** вопросы, основанные на реальных проблемах, на которые можно дать **однозначно правильный** ответ. **Абстрактные** и дискуссионные вопросы добавляют лишний «шум», споры и **отвлекают** сообщество от нуждающихся в помощи коллег, не внося **ничего** полезного.
>
> Вопросы должны быть **узкими** — если для ответа на вопрос требуется написать книгу, он явно не для этого ресурса.

Эти **не соревнования** имеют слишком общие формулировки и **должны быть закрыты**, независимо от каких-либо обстоятельств.

Однако, несмотря на это, по голосам и дискуссиям можно насчитать около сотни участников, поддержавших эти оффтопик-вопросы.

## Народ, вы чего?

Это откровенный оффтопик, не подходящий ни по правилам русского, ни по правилам «большого» Stack Overflow. Сайты сети Stack Exchange были созданы и существуют не для таких вопросов, независимо от того, нравится вам это или нет.

Некоторые утверждают, что людям хочется повеселиться в праздник и в ответах есть что-то полезное — ну, это как набухаться в библиотеке с попутным обменом опытом и не убрать за собой. Ну да, повеселились. Да, пришедшие после вас могут покопаться в кучке оставшегося мусора, лежащей в дальнем углу библиотеки, и найти какую-нибудь помятую бумажку с набросками какой-нибудь полезной для них информации. Но какой в этом толк? В итоге всё равно в библиотеке какой-то мусор валяется.

**Вы хотите копаться в мусорной свалке в поисках нужных вам знаний?** Лично я не хочу. Лично я хочу структурированную базу знаний, в которой поисковик на конкретный запрос сможет выдать мне релевантный пост из базы знаний и релевантные ответы к нету.

Поддерживая подобные вопросы, вы превращаете базу знаний в какую-то бесполезную флудилку и свалку из бессвязных примеров анимации. В будущем с вас будут брать пример другие участники и будут усиливать эту свалку. Если так продолжится и дальше, то в результате русский Stack Overflow превратится в неисправимый бесполезный бардак с нулевой полезностью в поисковиках.

**Stack Overflow — не форум, его цель — собирать и структурировать знания, а не хвастаться своими умениями клепать анимации в бессвязных вопросах-мусорках.**

Хочется надеяться, что в сообществе ruSO ещё остались люди, которые понимают суть Stack Overflow и придут навести порядок с использованием стандартных механизмов сайта.

К сожалению, модераторы бездействуют (и даже позорно делают попытки [узаконить замусоривание базы знаний](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9961)!), и Nicolas Chabanovsky тоже решил закрыть глаза на проблему (UPD: и хотя он написал правила проведения соревнований, он сам же их и нарушает). Некоторые участники даже эксплуатируют недоработки движка сайта и блокируют возможность закрытия вопросов через конкурсы.

## Поддерживая такие псевдоконкурсы, вы разрушаете всю изначальную идею Stack Overflow. Не надо так.

Comment: "модераторы бездействуют" Не бездействуют, но пока не понимают, как лучше это разрешить. От закрытия вопроса ничего не изменится. А как до людей донести мысль, что такие вопросы являются оффтопиком, я пока не знаю.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik ну это фактически бездействуют ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Но к модераторам у меня нет претензий, я понимаю, почему так происходит.

Comment: Кстати. "в администрацию «большого» Stack Overflow" - гиблое дело. Такое нужно решать на уровне своего сообщества. Англоговорящие сотрудники компании не смогут понять контекста.

Comment: @Sevastopol' сообщение изменено, поэтому такие комментарии не имеют смысла.

Comment: @Sevastopol' если можно поправить вопрос вместо удаления, то модераторы всегда предпочитали и предпочитают правку, а не удаление.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik фиг с ним с удалением, но как же бан на неделю за оскорбление?)

Comment: @andreymal там были упоминания конкретных людей, что не рекомендуется. Проблемные места вырезаны, сам вопрос важный для обсуждения. О каких банах речь?

Comment: @Sevastopol' там не было оскорблений. Поэтому вопрос мне не совсем понятен. Но может мы с Николаем что-то упустили. Какая часть текста и кого оскорбляет?

Comment: @Sevastopol' так упоминание особо наглых флудеров же убрали из вопроса, в чем проблема теперь?

Comment: _но проблема-то до сих пор не решена_, если так решать, то и не будет никогда решена. Последний ответ от активного организатора конкурсов с конкретными предложениями по формату (сценарию) оных, заминусован, конструктивное обсуждение предложения в комментариях проматривается с трудом. 

В итоге непонятно, то ли предложение полностью не подходит, то ли вообще никакого предложения не нужно, то ли просто автор не нравится.

Comment: @0xdb Под "решением проблемы" понимается закрытие спорных вопросов. Самый заплюсованный ответ от Николаса говорит, что конкурсы должны вписываться в формат, в противном случае они должны быть отредактированы или закрыты. В каком дальнейшем обсуждении есть необходимость?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он тут уже всех задолбал. Обсудили и хватит, зачем постоянно поднимать его снова?

Comment: @PavelMayorov толку-то от «обсудили», если проблема до сих пор не решена? Этот вопрос создан не для пустой болтовни, а для решения конкретной проблемы — и он **должен** периодически подниматься, пока эта самая проблема не будет каким-либо образом решена. Будь на Мете конкурсы — я бы тратил свой рейтинг на его поднятие, а так поднимаю как умею. И буду поднимать дальше.

Comment: @andreymal Я не вижу тут никакой проблемы. Большинство за конкурсы — значит им быть. Не согласны — голосуйте против и за закрыть, имеете на то право. _Majority rules_. А на практике доказано, что эти вопросы большинству нравятся, а правила не нарушают (ну по-крайне мере это спорно).

Comment: @VictorVosMottor во-первых, большинства не очень видно (конечно слышны отдельные сторонники вроде вас, но про большинство ещё не факт). Во-вторых, формулировка обсуждаемых псевдоконкурсов чётко нарушает правила (я неоднократно это разжёвывал ещё в апреле, и мне лень опять повторяться). В-третьих, если большинство и правда за конкурсы — значит нужно обновить правила сайта и отредактировать справку соответствующим образом. Пока этого не сделано — проблема не решена.

Comment: @andreymal, не надоело?

Comment: @avp а чему тут надоедать, если проблема не только не решена, но ещё и решила усилиться в последние пару дней? См. предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @andreymal, вам еще не надоело бороться за чистоту (или за что вы боретесь)? Не мешайте людям заниматься тем, что им нравится. Вам уже куча народа (imho) написала, что большинству нравятся эти конкурсы, соревнования и т.п.

Comment: @avp ну так обновите справку, разрешите такие общие вопросы в правилах сайта, сделайте объявление о новых правилах. Напишите сюда ответ вида «правила написаны, справка обновлена» — я поставлю галочку и заткнусь. Но почему все (даже Николай!) только мямлят в комментах, а конкретно взять и официально расширить онтопик никто не хочет? Возможно, потому что все всё-таки подсознательно понимают, что это нихрена не онтопик?

Comment: @andreymal, смиритесь, вы живете в обществе, где законы-правила это просто бумага, где если нельзя,  но очень хочется, то все-таки можно...

Comment: @avp это не мешает мечтать приблизиться к Прекрасной Р̶о̶с̶с̶и̶и̶ Базе Знаний Будущего )

Comment: Голос против. Несмотря на то, что мне ваши аргументы близки, тактика бесцельного редактирования - нет.

Comment: Кстати, по поводу голосования для закрытия с причиной "Обсудили и хватит, зачем постоянно поднимать его снова?". Закрытые вопросы всё так же можно редактировать и они будут подниматься снова.

Comment: ***"Поддерживая такие псевдоконкурсы, вы разрушаете всю изначальную идею Stack Overflow"*** - ровно наоборот

Comment: @avp с вами что-то очень не в порядке, если вы тему соблюдения чистоты и конструктивности базы знаний считаете чем-то испорченным.

Comment: @andreymal, вы в самом деле верите в "базу знаний"? Подобные вещи таким образом не делаются. Тут можно только набрать исходный материал для нее, отбирать годное содержимое все равно надо будет руками (и желательно не всеобщим голосованием данного контингента).

Comment: @avp работоспособность или неработоспособность подобных вещей — не повод слать имеющеся правила в пень. Если подобные вещи так не делаются — значит надо переименовать Stack Overflow обратно в ХэшКод, правила переделать, базу знаний отменить и объявить сайт обычным форумом. А пока этого не случилось — у меня есть все формальные основания ругаться по поводу нарушения правил и поддержки сообществом (причём в основном, похоже, старожилами с ХэшКода) этого нарушения правил, почему бы и нет

Comment: @andreymal, ну, у каждого тут свои мотивы и уровень законопослушности

Comment: Уважаемые коллеги, ну если уж Андрей таким вычеркиванием дал добро, то прошу вас помочь мне переоткрыть вопрос [Как нарисовать и анимировать символ (знак) российского рубля ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113095). Спасибо!)

Comment: Смысл теперь это поднимать, эта тема уже закрыта, добавлением страницы соревнований в справку. Даже если кто-то хочет что-то сделать здесь, в этой веренице флуда уже не разобраться. Ответь тогда уж в новой теме (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11271/) и поднимай ее, если это так важно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight эта страница не работает, правила продолжают нарушаться, а значит тема открыта и я буду продолжать её поднимать. Новая тема не имеет отношения к этой теме.

Comment: [предыдущие четыре голосования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10370/timeline) дали единогласный результат: оставить открытым. но кто-то вновь (в пятый раз) предложил закрыть этот вопрос. эх, такое бы упорство — да на благие цели…

Answer (score 15):

#### Обновление

По результатам обсуждений была добавлена новая страницу справки, шаблон  вопроса-соревнования и вопрос-песочница. [Более подробно в вопросе на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11193/).

---

> #### Коротко:
>
> В вопросах–соревнованиях, в том числе конкурсах вида «лучшая анимация» нет ничего плохого. Все, что им не хватает — строгих правил победы.

#### Stack Overflow имеет свой формат. Его следует соблюдать

Stack Overflow отличается от форумов форматом — вопросы на сайте задаются в виде прикладной проблемы, на которую можно дать однозначно верный ответ. Автор вопроса может принять ответ, который, по его мнению, решает проблему наилучшим способом. Принятый вопрос будет «закреплен» под ответом. Другие участники сортируют оставшиеся вопросы голосами за или против. Таким образом, лучший ответ, по мнению сообщества, будет сразу под принятым.

Любой вопрос, публикуемый на сайте, так или иначе должен вписываться в рамки механик движка (описанных выше). Если что–то выходит за пределы правил сайта или его тематики, то такие вопросы, скорее всего, будут закрыты. Конкурсы — не помеха, если я верно помню, модераторы могут их отменять.

#### Механики сайта и тематика сайта

На мой взгляд, было бы здорово, если бы мы все понимали термины одинаково. «Вопрос соответствует тематике сайта» — означает, что он про программирование или системное администрирование, [как описано в справке](/help/on-topic). «Вопрос соответветствует модели вопросов и ответов Stack Overflow» — означает, что [вопрос описывает конкретную проблему, на которую можно дать однозначный верный ответ](/help/how-to-ask).

Вопросы выше — тематически, они о программировании. Единственная проблема, которую я вижу — сделать их более специфичными (а-ля более детально описать что именно ожидается от ответов). Пример — [вопросы-соревнования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

#### Конкурсные вопросы всегда были и, надеюсь, будут!

Я [писал в ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10001/6) на подобный вопрос:

> У конкурсов в нашем сообществе богатая история: мы проводили различные конкурсы практически с первого дня существования сайта, причем как на Мете, так и на основном сайте, проводили и сами, и в партнерстве с другими сообществами. На наш взгляд, сами по себе конкурсы — это здорово.

Примеры конкурсных вопросов:

- [Алгоритм поиска максимальной суммы непрерывной подпоследовательности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129360/)
- [Автобусное расписание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/129355/6)
- [Кабак по случаю дня сисадмина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/131719/6)

Соревнования и конкурсы важны и нужны — это неотъемлемая часть формирования сообщества, да и просто, нельзя быть все время серьезными!  В вопросах–головоломках мы можем отдохнуть от работы, вспомнить университетские годы и проявить свои всеобъемлющие знания. Уверен, многие участники нашего сообщества могут отнести себя к хакерам (не путать с крекерами!) в своих областях и у них есть чему поучиться! Вопросы соревнования отлично для этого подходят!

#### Конкурс на Мете

Если вы планируете конкурс, который выходит за рамки правил сайта или одного вопроса, отличная альтернатива — Мета. Пример конкурсов на Мете — «https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8460/6». Способов оформить конкурс на Мете очень много!

Если вы хотите провести конкурс, но не уверены в подходе или просто хотите перестраховаться, пожалуйста, напишите ваши мысли [модераторам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) или [мне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile). Мы будем рады помочь.

#### Обновление: Задавать интересные вопросы сложно!

У нашего сообщества длинная история, в начале которой есть время, когда мои товарищи и я писали вопросы и ответы для нашей базы знаний. Мы поняли, что легко написать вопрос, вызванный реальной проблемой в коде и практически невозможно придумывать по 3- 5 вопросов в день на потоке не имея проблем в коде.

Вывод:

> Если есть участники, которые задают хорошие интересные вопросы, на которые публикуются хорошие интересные ответы — необходимо этих участников всячески поддерживать.

Интересны ли указанные вопросы? Однозначно. Приятно ли на них отвечать? 100%.

#### Что можно сделать?

Почему бы нам не начать с минимума: при необходимости, мы можем подсказать авторам подобных вопросов, как сделать их вопросы соответствующими правилам сайта (согласитесь, со стороны «незамыленным глазом» часто видно, что можно улучшить).

Повторюсь, вопросы создавать сложно, интересные — практически невозможно. На мой взгляд, хорошие вопросы, которые не соответствуют правилам сайта из за отсутствия двух-трех слов в заключительном предложении закрывать или минусовать точно не стоит, как минимум, из за уважения к труду автора. Единственное верное решение — внести улучшающую правку.

Если вы видите интересный вопрос, которому не хватает более четкой постановки вопроса, пожалуйста, внесите правку! Если автор откатит правку или выразит несогласие, пригласите автора в [основной чат сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33635/chmod-0770), сошлитесь на этот вопрос или ответ, объясните, что вопрос в текущем виде слишком общий, порекомендуйте как его улучшить.

***Давайте бороться «за», а не «против»!*** Создать базу знаний русскоязычного сообщества можно только вместе, работая сообща.

Comment: «проблема, которую я вижу — сделать их более специфичными», ну а пока они не специфичны, эти вопросы должны быть закрыты до уточнения. Но сообщество сопротивляется и не хочет ни уточнять, ни закрывать. О том и пост.

Comment: @andreymal как показала практика, вам не это нужно. По вашим тревогам я несколько раз правил вопрос соревнование НГ. И что? Вы раз, за разом слали тревоги

Comment: @Alexandr_TT нет, вы так и не сделали НГ достаточно специфичным даже после правок, и я вам об этом писал тогда в комментариях.

Comment: @andreymal НГ вопрос это старая традиция. Поэтому конкретно в том случае мне такое рвение не особо понятно =/

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik то, что я по глупости своей проглядел конкурс 2018-го и не поднял обсуждение проблемы ещё тогда, не делает такой конкурс автоматически традицией) А все озвученные мной ранее проблемы применимы и к нему тоже

Comment: @andreymal Новогодний алгоритм был и в 2016.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik ну так он на Мете был, а на Мете творите что хотите, я бы и [диалоги-о-работе] вернул) Всё моё возмущение относится только к основному сайту, на котором я более старых новогодних конкурсов не обнаружил (хотя не исключаю, что плохо искал)

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky Благодарю за тщательно продуманный, обстоятельный и полезный, на мой взгляд ответ! Я тоже вижу несомненную пользу в проведении конкурсов по анимации, не только из-за количества просмотров и заплюсованности и большого количества участников, а скорее из-за побочных факторов. Растет количество вопросов по анимации от новых участников, меняется сама суть вопросов, - не как сделать вот "такой то эффект, как на том сайте"  а уже конкретные вопросы с кодами собственных попыток. И это меня радует.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT по-моему вы выдумываете несуществующие вещи. Не вижу связи между конкурсами и другими вопросами.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT и не забывайте, что ваши новогодние псевдоконкурсы по-прежнему недостаточно специфичны, о чём Николай здесь и написал. А значит, формально, они должны быть закрыты.

Comment: От `они должны быть закрыты` у всех уже в ушах звенит. Не надоело? С таким подходом можно бОльшую часть вопросов закрыть к едрене фене, что только пагубно будет влиять на развитие сообщества. Не думаю, что собственники (именно собственники, а не модераторы, работники или кто-либо еще) ресурса одобрят подобные действия и призывы вот таких вот участников.

Comment: @Sevastopol' всё правильно, бо́льшая часть вопросов полезна только для их авторов, не увеличивает качество базы знаний, не добавляет релевантности в поиске и должна быть закрыта и впоследствии удалена. К сожалению, для этого не хватает человеческих ресурсов, да и наследие ХэшКода ещё разгребать как-то надо. Это отдельная проблема. И думаю, собственники решение этой проблемы вполне одобрят.

Comment: Дай вам волю, Вы всё закроете, причем вместе с сайтом. Как я отметил выше, да, такая позиция несомненно несет только вред ресурсу. Более того, она еще и опасна. И как такой экстремизм на SO допускается, не понимаю.

Comment: @Sevastopol' да, закрою, я вообще считаю, что правила нужно ещё более ужесточить во имя чистоты базы знаний :) Но это повлечёт за собой множество других проблем, поэтому я пока что революций не устраиваю и просто требую от вопросов соответствовать тем правилам, которые есть сейчас.

Comment: `да, закрою` Уважаемые модераторы, принимайте меры, вот вам участник, который в открытую призывает нанести вред сообществу. Уже не тема для размышлений, а время для конкретных действий. И пока кто-то будет закрывать глаза на такие призывы, кто-то скорее "закроет" сообщество.

Comment: @Sevastopol' единолично он ничего закрыть не сможет. Для закрытия всё так же нужно ещё 4 участника. Если уж они закроют вопрос, то система работает как надо. В этом и суть саморегулирующегося сообщества.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, при всём к Вам уважении, я понимаю это и знаю. Вопрос в другом. Не кажется ли Вам, что такая агрессия больше смахивает уже на экстремизм внутри сообщества, что очень опасно для сообщества и дает уже свои плоды?

Comment: @Sevastopol' такое рвение необычно, не скрою. Но пока я особо не замечал за ним, чтобы страдали полезные вопросы. Что у него, что у вас, я надеюсь, цели одинаковые - помочь другим людям и обогатить базу знаний. Поэтому это обсуждение и важно. Нужно решить, как такие вопросы можно подвести под формат сайта.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, да ну в самом деле какой формат, поставлен четкий сценарий, добавлен четкий ответ на этот сценарий, плюс вопрос как можно этот сценарий реализовать любым другим способом. Или мне здесь написать раскрытый и обосновывающий ответ? Ну нет у меня желания доказывать то, что не требуется в доказательствах. Считаю, что это исключительно принципиальная агрессивная позиция "борца за справедливость", не имеющая под собой никаких обоснований, но которая уже переросла в опасный экстремизм внутри сообщества.

Comment: @Sevastopol' чёткого сценария нет. Об этом уже говорили и модераторы, и даже сам Николай в этом ответе.

Comment: Чёткий сценарий есть, и он чёрным по белому описан в вопросе. И есть также не менее чёткий ответ на этот сценарий, плюс описание, каким образом этот сценарий реализован. А также имеются дополнительно чёткие ответы на мой чётко заданный вопрос. И не перестаю говорить спасибо всем участникам!

Comment: @Sevastopol', "Приемлемы любые другие текстовые эффекты, эффекты трансформации, абсолютно любые эффекты анимации без ограничений." К сожалению, это сложно назвать четко заданным вопросом.

Comment: Это вырвано из контекста. Читайте вопрос полностью и внимательно.

Comment: @Sevastopol' этого предложения вполне достаточно, чтобы полностью сделать вопрос слишком общим. Остальной текст уже не имеет значения, потому что он аннулируется этим предложением.

Comment: Это хорошо если автор не специально сформулировал вопрос в нечетком виде, такие вопросы достаточно легко привести в порядок. Перечисленные же в этой теме вопросы - специально сформулированы нечетко и в этом практически вся их суть, исправить их можно только нарушив намерения автора. Очевидно, такие правки будут откатываться.

Comment: Да, сам я не делал к этим вопросам никаких правок, потому что они однозначно станут нарушать намерениям авторов. А сами авторы моих намёков не понимают и вносить никаких правок не думают (Alexandr_TT пытался к новогодним конкурсам, но по факту всё равно ничего не изменилось)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky наведите порядок, пожалуйста. За полгода сообщество так и не потрудилось привести эти псевдоконкурсы в соответствие «формату» и продолжает разрушать всю идею SO.

Answer (score 9):

Неформатный вопрос =/= "мусорка". Как ни парадоксально, такие общие вопросы тоже могут генерировать качественные ответы. Как я уже писал, нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы в качестве исключения проводить такие конкурсы, например, на Новый Год. Но я согласен, что бесконечно плодить такое нельзя. Если на каждый чих вводить исключения, от правил ничего не останется. Часть работы модератора (управляющего) в том, чтобы идти против воли сообщества, когда это действительно нужно. Сейчас, мне кажется, такое время настало. Предлагаю модераторам сделать следующее:

1. Отменить текущий конкурс на вопросе про анимацию (это должно вернуть репутацию организатору).
2. Закрыть его и повесить историческую блокировку.
3. Предложить сторонникам проведения "неформатных" конкурсов создать предложение на мете, в котором описать подробно, в каком виде и с какой периодичностью они хотят их проводить.
4. Ввести правило, что конкурсы (т.е. механизм присуждения награды) можно объявлять только в вопросах, безоговорочно соответствующих правилам (из справки или принятых большинством голосов на мете). Люди используют конкурсы, чтобы быстрее получить помощь; и мы, отвечающие, используем конкурсы для нахождения интересных вопросов. Конкурсы не должны быть грязным политическим орудием.

Надо прекратить взаимные упреки и обсуждать по сути. Писать, что у участника полгода нет ни одного ответа, а только голоса на закрытие, недопустимо. Никто не обязан отвечать, каждый вносит свой вклад как хочет, в пределах правил. Но также недопустимо и называть мусором вопрос с кучей заплюсованных ответов, в которые участники вложили свой труд.

Answer (score 8):

Update 2.12.2020

Ответ немного переработан, перенесен из [вопроса-дубликата](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11097/28748)

### Предлагаю вариант возможного решения оформления анимационных конкурсов

Вопрос трудный, так как конкурсы анимации, отличаются от обычных конкурсов.

Хочу рассмотреть в деталях [**один конкурс**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1085360/28748), который был проведен до выхода этого топика и на примерах проанализировать все нюансы, как стартует конкурс, как проводится, как финиширует с выбором победителя.

*Более подробно, весь текст оформления вопроса можно посмотреть, перейдя по ссылке*

---

[**Как создать анимированную иконку Stackoverflow**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1085360/28748)

> Сценарий анимации:
>
> 1. Рисование контура корзины
> 2. Заполнение цветом контура
> 3. Последовательное появление 5-ти цветных полосок
> 4. Исчезновение полосок в обратном порядке.
> 5. Зацикливание появления, исчезновения цветных полосок.
>
> Как реализовать данный сценарий анимации иконки, используя одну из
> технологий, указанную в метках вопроса?

---

**Вопрос** Нарушает ли этот вопрос правила проведения конкурса?

---

- Заголовок вопроса не допускает разночтения.
- Дано изображение  и код иконки
- Задан чёткий сценарий анимации.
- Дан перечень меток, по которым автор конкурса хотел бы получить
  варианты ответа.

Допустим, автор конкурса немного знает анимацию SVG и хотел бы увидеть для освоения и саморазвития аналогичные варианты анимации CSS, Javascript, canvas, webgl.
Ведь аналогичные методы и приемы выполнения анимации взаимно дополняют друг друга.

В ответе  могут быть решения, как по одной метке, так и в комплексном использовании меток. (Будет и SVG и CSS и JS).
Автору важен результат, чёткое выполнение сценария анимации.

**Вот это строгое выполнение сценария анимации и нужно рассматривать, как вопрос, на который может быть дан однозначный ответ.**
А как внутри будет реализовано выполнение *конкретного пункта сценария*, отдается на откуп отвечающему.
Автор вопроса также может добавить дополнительные конкретные условия:

1. При наведении курсора анимация начинается в прямом направлении при уводе курсора в обратном направлении.
2. Тоже самое условие может  быть оговорено при первом и повтором клике.
3. Анимация после запуска бесконечно повторяется, пока не уведен курсор и т.д
4. Анимация после запуска бесконечно повторяется, пока не обновлена страница документа.
5. Анимация длится 4 секунды.

Предполагаю, что таких конкретных требований к оформлению вопроса, вполне достаточно, чтобы полностью соответствовать правилам проведения конкурса.

Условия выбора победителя конкурса очевидны, - побеждает та работа, которая наиболее точно выполнит все условия конкурса.

**Ответ**: конкурсный вопрос, на мой взгляд,  не нарушает правила.

---

### Выбор победителя конкурса

Из всех поступивших работ от участников конкурса, посетителям топика, наиболее понравился вот этот [**ответ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086216/28748)  Но  автор  выполнил только половину пунктов сценария.
Мне тоже очень понравился этот ответ, но к сожалению, условия конкурса были выполнены не полностью  и работа не рассматривалась, как кандидат на победу.

Из оставшихся ответов, четыре работы наиболее полно выполнили условия конкурсного задания.
Но победить может быть  только один и выбирать его предстоит организатору конкурса.

Может быть выбран не самый сильный и яркий ответ, но выбирается тот ответ, который в большей степени подошёл автору.

Как я понял, [**выбранный ответ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086439/28748) тоже понравился остальным участникам и особых обид и разочарований не было.

### Предлагаю:

Рассмотреть такие конкретные требования к проведению текущих конкурсов анимаций, которые уточняют, но не противоречат **слишком общим** правилам проведения конкурсов SO.
Если сообщество проголосует за такой вариант решения проблемы анимационных конкурсов, то надеюсь исчезнет взаимное непонимание и бесконечные разбирательства о правомерности проведения таких анимационных конкурсов.

### Update

Комментарии из [чата](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56233843#56233843) от **@yolosora**
<sub>Опубликовано с разрешения автора</sub>

> Ответ @Alexandr_TT с примером регламента конкурсов мне в целом
> нравится, но он не решает потенциальной проблемы которую я описал в
> комментарии к ответу A K. ( в теории может появится пользователь
> который каждый день будет флудить десятками вопросов вида "анимируйте
> буквы, трусы, самолет, бубенцы" и с этим уже ничего не сделаешь) Можно
> конечно не заниматься преждевременной оптимизацией регламента,
> понадеяться на адекватность комьюнити и в случае чего вернуться к
> обсуждению модификаций уже существующего регламента. Будет хотя бы от
> чего отталкиваться.

Перечень тем всегда можно оговорить, или по крупному - анимация элементов frontend. Или более подробно: иконки, меню, анимация веб страниц, модальных окон, текста, прокрутки страниц, прорисовка маршрутов на карте и т.д
Эти темы очень востребованы и актуальны при разработке и оформлении веб приложений

Давайте заодно, чтобы не откладывать в долгий ящик, обсудим и перечень допустим тем для конкурсов анимации.

Comment: Да, у конкурса анимированной иконки действительно нормальная формулировка, не допускающая слишком широких разночтений (контур корзины это мелочи), никаких «абсолютно любых эффектов анимации» и «по своему сценарию» в нём нет, и я к нему никаких претензий не имею. А вот у упомянутых здесь трёх вопросов формулировка по-прежнему слишком широкая и они по-прежнему должны быть или исправлены по образу и подобию «анимированной иконки», или всё же закрыты.

Comment: @Sevastopol' ирония, на мой взгляд здесь не совсем подходит. Надо как-то конструктивно, обезличенно искать решения и компромиссы. В противном случае мы никогда не найдем решения, которое бы устроило всех

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, разве я против конструктивного поиска решений? Я целиком и полностью согласен с управляющим сообществом Nicolas Chabanovsky в том, что необходимо **бороться «за»** хорошие вопросы, ответы и конкурсы. Более того, даже если в будущем будут появляться пусть даже и **слишком общие заголовки и слишком общие тексты вопросов**, тем не менее стараться их всячески поддерживать, продвигать и стимулировать, а не пытаться подогнать под какой-нибудь единый шаблонный образец, и тем более не стремится их блокировать. Это мое личное мнение.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Я специально рассмотрел на конкретном примере, который содержит чёткий вопрос, но одновременно оставляет широкие возможности для проявления творческого подхода в ответах. Никто ведь не запрещает реализовать, тот или иной пункт сценария как он умеет, добавляя те же трансформации и другие анимационные эффекты. И на ответы уже не распространяются ограничивающие правила, за несоблюдение которых можно закрыть топик. В крайнем случае заминусуют или удалят этот ответ

Comment: @Sevastopol' продвигать и стимулировать нарушение правил? Пожалуй, не стоит.

Comment: Приведённый пример - неплох и именно такими лично я вижу эталонные конкурсы по анимации / дизайну, однако в силу малой полезности вопроса как такового (несмотря на наличие качественных и полезный ответов) - я бы предложил ввести временные ограничения вида «один конкурс в Х недель» и создавать такие конкурсы по предварительному согласованию тематики. В идеале от лица нейтрального аккаунта (на случай если кого-то нервирует фарм репутации с подобного рода вопросов), но мне это не важно.

Comment: @Sevastopol' т.к. ruSO - база знаний вида Вопрос-Ответ, а не околоайти флудильня - в идеале бы все посты подгонять подгонять под единые шаблонные образцы

Comment: @yolosora **я бы предложил ввести временные ограничения вида «один конкурс в Х недель» и создавать такие конкурсы по предварительному согласованию тематики.** мы с вами видимо читаем разные правила или вы их трактуете по своему? [В справке об ограничении количества конкурсов сказано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)  **Одновременно можно начать только три конкурса.**  Также не идет речи ни о каком предварительном согласовании тематики. Если вам все же хочется внедрить свои правила, добейтесь этого официальным путем, через SE

Comment: @yolosora **база знаний вида Вопрос-Ответ, а не околоайти флудильня** Если вы говорите это о конкурсах то я бы попросил вас воздержаться от навешивания негативных ярлыков. **На вас никто не нападает**  Цель моего ответа была направлена на перевод обсуждения конкурсов анимации  в спокойное, конструктивное обсуждение. Но как показывает ход голосования, противники проведения конкурсов ещё не готовы к этому. В конце концов, не любишь конкурсы, чей-то ник вызывает раздражение, можно же пройти мимо, не открывать топик, поберечь свою нервную систему.

Comment: @yolosora если вопрос соответствует правилам сайта, то и ограничивать что-либо нет никакого смысла. Если же вопрос нарушает правила, то нужно или на Мете явно договориться, что [нарушать правила это хорошо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9961), или же закрыть нарушающий правила вопрос.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT под конкурсами я имел ввиду именно вопросы-соревнования, а не навешивание наград. Согласования тематики и ограничения количества вопросов-соревнований - нет (кроме прецедента с новогодним конкурсом), поэтому я и озвучиваю это в формате предложения. Про околоайти флудильню я сказал потому что засилье подобными бессмысленными вопросами (не только касательно соревнований по анимации) создает ощущение что ты находишься на каком-нибудь киберфоруме или айти разделе ответов маилру с вопросами «а как анимировать булки», «а как сделать чтобы у зайца уши качались» и тд

Comment: @Alexandr_TT более того, т.к. графический дизайн в разрезе программирования является онтопиком - интуитивно кажется очевидным, что возможность соревноваться для профессионалов и любителей в этой области - должна быть (по аналогии с код гольфом), но по аналогии с гольфом эти соревнования либо должны быть подогнаны под существующие правила, либо онтопик должен быть расширен, должны быть озвучены конкретные требования к подобным соревнованиям и впредь они должны этим требованиям следовать. Пока что кроме Новогоднего конкурса решений не было и вопросы должны закрываться.

Comment: И я не вижу в этом нападок на конкретных пользователей и борьбы «против», на месте вопросов-соревнований по анимации могли оказаться любые другие группы вопросов (если бы был заметный прецедент и вопросы можно было бы сгруппировать по некому критерию)

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл поискать подобные обсуждения на старшем SO

Comment: А мне вот интересно следующее. Где я могу почитать в правилах RUso про `Заголовок слишком общий. Вопрос тоже слишком общий. Так что все они слишком общие.`? Где есть такое чёткое определение такой формулировке и по каким критериям собственно такая формулировка определяется и вешается ярлыком на вопрос? А также мне интересно, где я могу почитать в правилах RUso о том, что конкурс не должен быть объявлен `без предварительного обсуждения` с несогласными? Покажите мне, пожалуйста, такие выдержки из правил, где описаны такие чёткие формулировки. Спасибо.

Comment: Один вопрос определять и объявлять как `Заголовок слишком общий. Вопрос тоже слишком общий. Так что все они слишком общие.`, а другой нет. По какому принципу согласно правилам RUso это определяется? Где есть такое чёткое определение такой формулировке и по каким критериям собственно такая формулировка определяется, согласно правилам RUso? Покажите мне, пожалуйста, такие выдержки из правил.

Comment: @Sevastopol' [вопрос слишком общий — если для ответа на ваш вопрос требуется написать целую книгу или существует множество верных ответов, он, скорее всего, не соответствует формату вопросов и ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @Alexandr_TT конкурс или не конкурс никак не влияет на закрытие. Закрываются "общие вопросы". А его соревновательность особо на это не влияет.

Comment: Но т.к. сообщество решило, что соревнованиям быть, то, чтобы удовлетворять правилам (хоть и с натяжкой) и были введены ограничения/критерии.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik я выдвинул вполне конкретное предложение, чему полностью посвящен этот пост. Хорошо бы написать отдельный ответ. Также я понял из комментариев, что у противников проведения конкурсов с "широкими условиями" нет никаких претензий к данному образцу.

Comment: В справке указаны слишком общие формулировки. Меня же интересует, как Вы определили, что выше приведенные вопросы являются слишком общими? Какими критериями Вы пользовались, чтобы определить, что эти вопросы слишком общие, кроме как только основываясь на личное мнение? А также, как вопрос может быть _не_ слишком общим, учитывая что к вопросу имеется возможность добавления до пяти меток, а это значит, что абсолютно разные технологии могут быть применены к решению вопроса, и это уже возможность дать множество верных ответов, и даже написать книгу. Несоответствие..

Comment: @Sevastopol' Система позволяет поставить 5 меток, правилами нигде конкретно не запрещено ставить максимальное количество меток, значит можно это делать. А вот насчет остального, можно спорить до бесконечности и каждая сторона будет находить свои контрдоводы. Я предложил свой компромиссный вариант - вопрос отредактировать, в соответствии с предложенным шаблоном, а в ответах никто не запрещает людям проявить свое творчество.

Comment: Если ответы будут что-то серьезно нарушать, то у сообщества всегда есть возможность их заминусовать, а модераторам на этом основании их удалить. Хотите я сделаю правку вопроса вашего конкурса? Не понравится, всегда можете откатить

Comment: @Sevastopol' Ведь главная ценность не вопрос, а ответы. Ответам с копипастом в таких топиках конечно недопустимы и это можно явно оговорить в вопросе. Ценность в оригинальном коде, в свежести идей и подходов, на что и направлены подобные конкурсы.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, вы пожалуйста для начала попробуйте сделать правку НГ2020 и Анимация новогодней ёлочки, приведя их в строгое соответствие с предложенным Вами шаблоном. А я уже по аналогии, возможно, постараюсь повториться. Как вы на это смотрите?

Comment: @Sevastopol' я смотрю на это отрицательно, так как это отдельная тема. И есть четкие обоснования почему нельзя конкурс НГ вогнать в рамки проведения конкурсов. Вы скопировали полностью мою подачу открытия конкурса НГ на свой конкурс. Но это были совсем иные времена, когда нужно было людей расшевилить, поднять на написание творческих ответов. Сейчас уже все в курсе и не требуется такая подача конкурсных вопросов.

Comment: @Sevastopol' вопрос закрывается консенсусом из 5 человек именно потому, что чётких критериев нету.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT мне нужно выделить время, чтоб основательно подумать над ответом. Постараюсь на след. неделе.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, чтобы понять, что это абсолютно разные конкурсы, и в них нет ничего общего и похожего, а тем более скопированного, достаточно их просто сравнить. Некрасиво переходить на необоснованные обвинения, прикрывая свои вопросы, созданные совсем недавно. Это какие такие иные времена? Вы о них прямо как о лихих 90х. Эти иные времена были четыре месяца назад и год назад, и не нужно было никого поднимать или расшевеливать, все мы здесь были в эти иные времена и хорошо помним, что обстановка была обычная, полностью рабочая и творческая.

Comment: @Sevastopol' я вас ни в чём ни обвинял. давайте скажу по другому, похожая подача конкурсов, но я был первый, поэтому и сказал, что скопировали. Ничего в этом обидного нет. Но если обсуждение заходит в тупик, надо быть более договороспособным. А сейчас складывается ситуация, когда ни одна из сторон не хочет пойти навстречу Помните мои слова к Вам про "шаги и выравнивание?" Тогда по моему Вы были согласны

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, тогда зачем вешать такие ярлыки на вопросы как `слишком общие`. Всё верно вы говорите, это лишь консенсус из 5 человек, которые приняли такое решение. Но это вовсе не значит, что это так. Здесь не может быть какого-то единого мнения или шаблона. Сегодня 5 человек закрыли, значит общий. Завтра 5 человек откроют, значит уже не общий. Ну так же не бывает. Зачем вы блокируете интересные вопросы и идете тем самым вразрез с мнением управляющего сообществом Nicolas Chabanovsky?

Comment: @Sevastopol' у меня такое ощущение, что вы ответ Николая совсем не читали. Это, во-первых. Во-вторых, и я это уже сотни раз писал, решение принимает сообщество. В своём ответе Николай высказал своё мнение как участник сообщества. Другие участники сообщество могут относиться к его ответу по-разному.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, выше я писал комментарий, что целиком и полностью согласен с управляющим сообществом Nicolas Chabanovsky в том, что необходимо бороться «за» хорошие вопросы, ответы и конкурсы. Но не за шаблоны. Но раз Вы пытаетесь идти навстречу, и инициировали этот вопрос, предложив для этого шаблон, так я Вам и предлагаю в ответ, начните, пожалуйста, со своих вопросов, и мы обязательно последуем Вашему примеру.

Comment: @Sevastopol' А разве проведенный конкурс, предложенный в качестве шаблона плохо прошел, не было хорошей активности, хороших ответов?. Чем плох предложенный пример? Или по инерции будем протестовать, как сделали люди, заминусовав моё предложение в этом топике, но согласившись, что приведенный пример вполне подходит под шаблон проведения конкурсов

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, чтобы не было протестов, нужно переходить к делу. Вы выдвинули свое предложение? Значит стоит теперь подать всем такой пример, и отредактировать все свои спорные вопросы согласно предложенному Вами шаблону. Этот поступок будет подтверждать Ваши серьезные намерения. В данном топике Андрея указано три вопроса (а не про иконку SO), которые нервируют некоторых участников. Ждем теперь Ваших первых шагов, и будем следовать Вашему примеру. Справедливо? Несомненно!

Comment: @Sevastopol' Я повторюсь, конкурсы НГ невозможно вогнать в правила проведения конкурсов, потому что в связи со своей специфичностью они действительно очень широкие. Много объектов анимации, много анимационных эффектов, гирлянды, фейерверки, всякие зверушки, Дед мороз и снегурочка, как не правь, вопрос останется слишком общий. Ваш конкурс легко подогнать под предлагаемый образец, нужно лишь убрать абзац начинающийся:  **Рассматриваются любые варианты и ответы ..**  Если вы уберите, это как-то ущемляет Ваши права? Но конкурс уже тогда будет вписываться в правила.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, Вы очевидно забыли, что данную тему некоторые участники подняли не только по причине моих якобы общих вопросов, но и Ваших. Гляньте, пожалуйста, прокрутите страничку вверх, и ознакомьтесь с перечнем вопросов. Их три. Один мой и два Ваши. А Вы пытаетесь на меня навесить еще и свои грехи. Не стыдно ли так прилюдно поступать? Вы меня конечно простите, и поймите меня правильно, но Вы инициировались с таким предложением, Вам и рулить. Очень даже легко можно подогнать исключительно все вопросы, в т.ч. и новогодние, под предложенный Вами шаблон. Не стоит лукавить, не искушайте зверушек)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, возраст не может быть поводом для гордости. К сожалению, Вы ошиблись в определениях или неверно истолковали переписку. Кроме того, как Вы знаете, здесь достаточно взрослых людей. Да, Вы правильно понимаете, возраст здесь не аргумент. Поэтому, еще раз, поймите меня, пожалуйста, правильно, Вы выдвинули свое предложение, и это предложение равно для всех участников, и здесь не может быть никаких исключений. А Вы себя ведете так, словно Вас это не касается (поэтому понимайте, пожалуйста, шутку верно). Но если не понимаете, то вопрос прямой: это предложение касается всех, но кроме Вас?

Answer (score 5):

## Ну в конце концов участвовать в таких конкурсах просто весело!

*Да* такие вопросы *не соответствуют тематике сайта*.

**Но постойте,  это не значит, что их надо сразу вырезать на корню.**
На правах личного мнения (ну а я все-таки занимаю 10-е место по кол-во полезных тревог, значит мне можно хоть чуть-чуть, но доверять):

Eсли эти вопросы нравятся сообществу, набирают большое количество голосов за, не закрываются и достаточно редки, то их вполне можно оставить — они же не мешают! Есть такое правило: исключение только подтверждает правило ;).

> Stack Overflow — не форум, его цель — собирать и структурировать знания, а не хвастаться своими умениями клепать анимации в бессвязных вопросах-мусорках.

Да вы правы, но все-таки от [таких вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109879/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-count-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-drf) тоже не очень много пользы.

Comment: Нет, они очень сильно мешают в результатах поиска. Человек, зайдя в такой вопрос, ища конкретную анимацию в гугле, увидит мешанину разных ответов и расстроится, и ему будет совсем не весело. Такие вопросы **вредны**, а веселиться надо в более предназначенных для этого местах

Comment: @andreymal Можете пример запроса в гугл и респонса?

Comment: Не проиндексировалось ещё. Но если не начинать принимать меры уже сейчас, то через пару лет подобных вопросов случится мусорка. Нужно смотреть в будущее.

Comment: И да, единичные случаи подобных вопросов, вероятно, ничего существенного не испортят, поэтому на новогодних конкурсах я так сильно тему раньше не поднимал. Однако новый такой неновогодний псевдоконкурс от другого участника — это уже звоночек, и появляется вероятность, что за ним последуют третий, четвёртый, десятый, сотый вопросы-мусорники — а это будет уже трагедия. Поэтому я поднимаю шумиху уже сейчас, чтобы пресечь проблему на корню, пока мои слова про вред не превратились из предположения в реальность.

Comment: `Не проиндексировалось ещё`?? Спасибо, повеселили))

Comment: Victor VosMottor thanks Monica, в какой-то степени поддерживаю вас. Но вот если бы эти вопросы действительно не соответствовали тематике сайта, тогда это другое дело и был бы повод поспорить. Но они еще как ей соответствуют, выше комментировал по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

**@Anton Menshov**
[ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11165/28748) в одном из топиков

> Проблема с "конкурсами" будет решаться. Надеюсь, что менее
> радикальными способами, чем было недавно продемонстрировано.

*Наверное и мне можно и нужно высказать свои мысли и пожелания по поводу будущих правил.*

Сразу уточню, что речь пойдёт не о конкурсах НГ, которые проводятся раз в год, тут видимо нужно упоминание в справке, что конкурсы НГ скорее  исключение из правил.

Как написано в этом [комментарии:](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11097/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F#comment46948_11097)

**@Kromster**

> Такие "конкурсы", конечно, офтопик, но раз в год - можно :-)

Но нельзя допустить, чтобы одна часть сообщества, которая против конкурсов навязала свою волю по закрытию конкурсов, по убиранию их в  мусорный ящик.

---

---

### О правилах

Надеюсь, что разрабатываемые  правила о текущих анимационных конкурсах, наконец-то создадут не-то чтобы, конструктивную, дружелюбную атмосферу вокруг конкурсов, *это наверное невозможно*, но хотя бы, как-то исключат в будущем вероятность возникновения подобных конфликтов между сторонниками и противниками.

Написание таких правил сверхтрудная задача. Так как анимационные конкурсы сильно отличаются от обычных конкурсов.   И должны быть внесены, какие-то дополнения, разъяснения в справку.

Я не хотел бы, чтобы проблема  была решена в стиле, - нет конкурса - нет проблем.

А именно к этому склоняют сообщество противники конкурсов, выдвигая такие предложения, как сделать `общими`, `ставить на блокировку`, `разделить одну  целую анимацию на составляющие её, простые части` и тд. и тп., то есть я вижу в комментариях стремление противников конкурсов, создать такие правила, чтобы организация и проведение конкурсов стала бы просто неинтересной организатору конкурса и её участникам. В стиле, а **чтобы неповадно было участвовать.**

На самом деле, анимационные конкурсы, при соответствующем оформлении и выборе тем, например анимация веб страниц, наполняющих её элементов разметки и анимационных персонажей на странице, это 100% онтопик.
К тому же очень востребованный в современном веб строительстве.

Но если в справке будут только одни словесные формулировки, то при особой изощренности интеллекта и горячем желании истолковать их в свою пользу,  вероятность конфликтов будет весьма высока.
Как говорится в пословице:
**[Закон — что дышло: куда повернёшь — туда и вышло](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%E2%80%94_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE:_%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%91%D1%88%D1%8C_%E2%80%94_%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE)**

Поэтому для обсуждения предоставлен  [**образец проведения конкурса**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1085360/28748), по которому сейчас нет разногласий, по крайней мере с ТС этого топика. Но мнение высказано не чётко,  что он не нарушает правил проведения конкурсов.

[Цитата:](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11097/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F#comment47066_11124)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой комментарий, где ТС более чётко высказал своё отношение к образцу конкурсов, как 100% удовлетворяющий требованиям, это было в апреле при первом обсуждении образца,  он стёр. И это настораживает, хотя любой может и написать и удалить свой комментарий.
*Слово дал, слово взял...*

Сегодня одно мнение, завтра может быть другое. При желании можно придраться и к телеграфному столбу.
***Поэтому нужна какая-то гарантия. Чтобы при новых конкурсах анимации, которые соответствуют образцу  можно было бы всегда отослать к разделу этой справки о анимационных конкурсах и в зародыше погасить конфликт.***

[Топик с обсуждением образца](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10397/28748)

Answer (score -2):

Ну сам же говоришь: *"сообщество поддерживает"* - а это главное. Раз поддерживает, значит таким вопросам быть :-)

Comment: Тогда нужно исправить правила, в которых жирными буквами написать «общие и абстрактные вопросы разрешены, задавайте на здоровье»

Comment: @andreymal, когда эти вопросы [только что пытались обсудить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10319/178988), вопрос просто закрыли как дубликат ;)

Comment: Если жирное «это не соревнования» закроют дубликатом про соревнования, я окончательно потеряю веру в человечество

Comment: @Qwertiy проблема моего вопроса в том, что я апеллировал к соревнованиям. Он был правильно закрыт как дубликат. В этом плане у andreymal лучше. Но всё ещё не понятно, что с этим делать, учитывая, что часть участников поддерживает оффтоп.

Comment: "Раз поддерживает, значит таким вопросам быть". Нет. Расширение онтопика у нас происходит через Мету. Все будущие подобные вопросы я буду закрывать как общие до тех пор, пока на Мете не будет принято решения по ним.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik кстати, а причина закрытия «необходимо конкретизировать» вроде бы захардкожена в движок сайта? Если да, то это плюс один знак, что подобный оффтопик обсуждению в принципе не подлежит)

Comment: @andreymal захардкожены. Мы можем править лишь часть причин в пункте "Специфичная для сообщества причина".

Answer (score -2):

Ну что же, отмечая изменения в вопросе, а именно:

> - <s>Как нарисовать и анимировать символ (знак) российского рубля</s> (исправлен, см. историю правок)
> - <s>Как анимировать слово StackOverflow</s> (исправлен, см. историю правок)

и раз уж наш всеми уважаемый участник @andreymal и главный борец за чистоту базы знаний вынес такое решение, то призываю неравнодушных участников переоткрыть вопрос [Как нарисовать и анимировать символ (знак) российского рубля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1113095/377637).

На протяжении всего этого долгого времени оба вопроса так и небыли закрыты. Кроме выше упомянутого. Этот вопрос был закрыт одним кликом одним модератором, который в один момент просто воспользовался своим преимуществом и не дал свободного выбора путем голосования простым участникам. Такое действие, на мой взгляд, является не совсем справедливым. Это конечно моё сугубо личное мнение. По крайней мере, если бы я был модератором, то уважал бы свободу выбора каждого участника, и в таких подобных случаях/ситуациях не пользовался бы инструментами модератора, иначе я считал бы, что совершил низкий поступок.

Однако, главная цель этого ответа заключается в другом. Мне хотелось бы поблагодарить всех тех участников, которые отозвали свои голоса "*против*" этих двух вопросов после их правки. Кто-то даже, отозвав голос "*против*", проголосовал "*за*", но это уже личное дело каждого. Для меня важнее просто отсутствие голоса "*против*", потому что я понимаю, что некоторые участники, а таковых совсем немного, голосовали "*против*" совсем не потому, что вопросы "*не отражают стремления разобраться; они непонятны или не несут пользы*", а совершенно по другой причине. Согласен, у каждого свое видение на подобные конкурсные вопросы, и каждый по-своему прав. Поэтому, спасибо вам за честность, и за справедливость.

Всем добра!

Answer (score -6):

К сожалению, кто-то так и не прислушался, не вчитался, и в итоге ничего таки не понял (или вероятнее всего даже не захотел понять), что [написал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10374/377637) [@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky).

Удивляет, неужели бывает настолько крепким самомнение в собственной уверенности, или это просто какой-то принцип? И как результат, идет отторжение в ответ на такое глупое конвульсивное от безысходности давление. И пропадает всякий интерес участвовать казалось бы в общем процессе. Уходишь. Возвращаешься. И видишь те же знакомые конвульсии, которые не прекращаются, потому что возникают по будильнику, который установлен таким образом, чтобы напоминал каждый раз через заранее установленный определенный промежуток времени. И такая система будет работать ещё наверняка долго, до тех пор, пока не изменится сам механизм, который влияет на тот самый общий процесс.

Кое-кто мне однажды сказал такую фразу: "должно быть как в лучших университетах страны". Сказано конечно громко, красиво. Но к сожалению, такие слова чаще всего оказываются просто пустым звуком. Ну а ты сам то что сделал, чтобы так было? Так делай что-нибудь, чтобы мнение о тебе сложилось положительное и не выглядел ты глупо и смешно.

Comment: Ну почему же, я вполне прислушался. В самом начале его ответа написано: **«Stack Overflow имеет свой формат. Его следует соблюдать».** Вот я и требую соблюдения формата.

Comment: @andreymal, вы себя почувствовали главным героем этого короткого сообщения? А почему собственно вы решили, что речь идет о вас? Какое же у вас высокое самомнение. И еще, вы всегда читаете только заголовки, которые в самом начале и написаны большим и жирным шрифтом?

Comment: Я-то читаю всё всегда целиком, а вы, похоже, даже заголовков за прошедшие полгода не потрудились прочитать.

Comment: @andreymal, вы считаете заголовки конструктивным сообщением? Ни флейм, а констатация факта. Вот и читайте, пожалуйста, всё всегда целиком, чтобы общение строилось на грамотной основе, а не на пустой полемике в ответ, и тогда будет интересно с вами общаться. А пока что нет.

Comment: Я уже полгода выстраиваю общение на грамотной основе, но вы старательно сопротивляетесь. Вы явно не заинтересованы в конструктивной дискуссии — что, впрочем, неудивительно: если перестать давить на жалость, «веселье», «прекрасные половины человечества» и «навязчивая навязчивость ой-ой-ой» — псевдоконкурс вмиг улетит на закрытие как нарушающий правила сайта. Вот вы и флеймите как умеете.

Comment: @andreymal, я не делаю ровным счетом ничего, чтобы, как вы говорите, сопротивляться. Это ваши конвульсии, нетерпимость, агрессия, нападки, давление и именно "навязчивое навязывание", которые сводятся к одному всеми уже известному словосочетанию, и вы пытаетесь это выдать за общение на грамотной основе, и которые абсолютно бессильны против уже выстроенной системы. И каким бы образом в дальнейшем не менялась бы ситуация, это уже не будет иметь никакого значения, потому что вы уже проиграли.