# Почему закрыт конкурс по C++?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Имеем [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212409/185348) с конкурсом «Hello World на C++», который почему-то закрыт как дубликат вопроса про «Hello, World с пустой функцией main». Кроме того, конкурс получил 9 отрицательных голосов и ни одного положительного (кроме моего).

Я не совсем понимаю, почему этот конкурс закрыт:

- у него есть четкая и конкретная задача — вывести строку `Hello, world` в стандартный поток вывода;
- у него есть четко оговоренные правила — запрещено использовать буквы для формирования текста в исходном коде программы, а также запрещено использовать функции вывода в консоль в явном виде.

Я бы, например, с удовольствием поучаствовал в таком конкурсе.

---

Ну это какой-то сюр, друзья. Конечно, я поднял этот вопрос с некой долей иронии в свете последних событий. Лично я не вижу никакой принципиальной разницы между пресловутыми конкурсами анимации и эти конкурсом по выводу `Hello, world`. Более того, этот конкурс даже более конкретен ибо не подразумевает разночтений — в результате работы программы получим определенную строку в `stdout`.

Меня, правда, немного смущает вот это: «как **прикольней** всего написать», но если подумать, то все конкурсы анимации это и спрашивают, только в завуалированной форме.

И если уж разрешать конкурсы, то разрешать все, а не только по определенным меткам. А то это какие-то двойные стандарты получаются.

---

В общем-то, я хотел сказать о том, что подобный конкурс ничем не отличается от конкурсов анимации, но первый — закрыт, вторые — до сих пор открыты.

В комментариях ниже пишут, что в этом конкурсе нет четких критериев победы — «прикольней всего» — это не критерий, но точно также не оговорены критерии победы в вопросах про [анимацию рубля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113095/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f), [анимацию слова StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105132/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-stackoverflow), [новогодний конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061127/%d0%9d%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-2020-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0).

Это не призыв открывать/закрывать что-либо, скорее просьба объяснить мне, в чем принципиальная разница между этим конкурсом по С++ и конкурсами анимации?

*Мне иногда кажется, что инструменты голосования и закрытия используются по велению правой пятки участника, а не по их прямому назначению.*

Comment: Не хватает критериев победы, если это голоса, то нужно оговорить явно. Проголосовал за переоткрытие, как минимум это не дубликат.

Comment: Аккаунт создан 2 дня назад. Мы, конечно, подразумеваем всегда "добрые намерения", но на фоне драм с конкурсами кажется, что это просто троллинг)

Comment: Проголосовал в очереди "оставить закрытым". Что за критерий победы такой - "прикольней всего"? В чем измерить? Можно конечно переоткрыть и закрыть с другой причиной, но не вижу смысла. Ну и тут серия дубликатов вчера была от одного человека с двух учеток, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/418910/ihurt, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/418920/ihurt . Вряд ли троллинг, слишком уж явное "новичковское" поведение.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, я, возможно, несколько неудачно выразил мысль в вопросе, но о том и речь, что подобный конкурс ничем не отличается от конкурсов про анимацию, но первый — закрыт, вторые — открыты. В конкурсах про рубль, анимацию слова StackOverflow, НГ, также не оговорены критерии победы. Я не ратую за подобные конкурсы, просто мне показалось ироничным что один конкурс закрывают, другие — оставляют открытыми

Comment: @insolor, см. мой комментарий выше.

Comment: @eanmos есть очевидная разница: качественно оформленный вопрос (хоть и не подходящий формально по правилам), способный вызвать интерес участников, и надоедливые дубли с кривым оформлением и невнятными условиями. Формально (с точки зрения правил) конечно разницы нет, но в целом я понимаю тех, кому нравятся "неформатные" конкурсы, и статус кво меня бы вполне устроил.

Comment: @insolor, (1) почему конкурс C++  оформлен некачественно? В нем нет орфографических или грамматических ошибок, в нем нормальное форматирование. Ну слово «конкурс» в заголовке транслитом написано, единственная проблема в оформлении, которое я вижу.  (2) О том и речь, что формально разницы нет, а по факту — разница налицо.

Comment: Я понял, что вы пытались выразить. Анимационные конкурсы действительно должны быть закрыты. Но и этот в текущем виде тоже, только не дубликатом, а как слишком общий. Помимо условий сами правила бы надо доработать, если нельзя использовать вывод в консоль, но можно, скажем, fprintf, то решение слишком очевидно. И он столько минусов наловил, что его бы пришлось все равно перезадавать заново, иначе его мало кто увидит.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight это был 4 вопрос от этого человека (со второй учетки, см ссылки в моем комментарии выше), причем на первых двух вопросах всего -2, проще было бы первый или второй нормально дооформить, а не спамить дубликатами.

Comment: Принципиальная разница в том, что этот противники конкурсов (любители строгих правил) быстро распознали и оценив как явную провокацию набросились на него, в то время как остальные участники на этот новый конкурс просто не отреагировали (не интересно). Кстати, в одной из его реинкарнаций я в комментарии написал вывод в stdout как write массива из пары double

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сразу скажу, что я нейтрально отношусь к любым соревнованиями, и ниже пишу ответ без привлечения лишних сущностей.

Краткий ответ, почему конкретно этот вопрос был закрыт - один из участников предложил закрыть вопрос как дубликат, а автор вопроса подтвердил закрытие:

[image: Скриншот]

Длинный ответ: это 4-й вопрос из серии из 5 однотипных вопросов от одного и того же человека с двух учетных записей (в хронологическом порядке от более старых к более новым, в скобках - рейтинг вопроса на момент написания данного ответа):

- **Участник [ihurt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/418910/ihurt) (id 418910)**:

  - [КОНКУРС Hello World [закрыт]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212383) (-2)

    [Исходный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1212383/1) вариант этого вопроса (для понимания контекста):

    > **КОНКРУС ХЕЛОВРД**
    > КАК ПРИКОЛЬ НЕЙ ВСЕГО НАПИСАТЬБ ХЕЛОВОРД НА СИ ПЛЮС ПЛЮС? КОНКУПУС
  - [ХЕЛОВОРД КОНУКРС [дубликат]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212389) (-2)
  - [конкурс хеловород [дубликат]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212400) (-8)
- **Участник [ihurt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/418920/ihurt) (id 418920)**:

  - [Конкурс на вывод строки HelloWorld средствами С++ [дубликат]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212409) (-9) <-- обсуждаемый вопрос
  - [helloworld конкурс учавствуй! [дубликат]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212423) (-8)

Т.е. проблема не только с этим вопросом, а со всей серией вопросов.

Я думаю, что автору вопроса нужно было дооформить один из первых вопросов, а не тратить время на бессмысленные дубликаты, тогда бы не было серии закрытий и кучи минусов.

Что делать сейчас - просто переоткрыть вопрос т.к. указанный дубликат не является дубликатом вопроса на самом деле. Как вариант, можно этот вопрос оставить как есть, перенести содержимое в самый первый вопрос (как менее заминусованный) и переоткрыть его.

Comment: Добавлю, что самый первый вопрос был написан в трололо-стиле: "_КОНКРУС ХЕЛОВРД

КАК ПРИКОЛЬ НЕЙ ВСЕГО НАПИСАТЬБ ХЕЛОВОРД НА СИ ПЛЮС ПЛЮС? КОНКУПУС_". И это определило отношение к автору.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, согласен, стоит об этом сказать) Добавил в ответ

Comment: Документально подтвердить не смогу, но по моим ощущениям, обычный новичек, вопрос которого сходу не удался, не сможет прорваться через нашу существующую систему и бросит попытки наладить свою работу на этом сайте. Возможно сужу по себе и разным сайтам, где хотел что-нибудь заказать.

Comment: @avp, я тоже считаю что это обычный новичок. По поводу попыток "наладить" лучше промолчу.

Comment: @avp все же напишу: на мой взгляд - не было никаких попыток наладить работу, была попытка именно прорваться сквозь систему. Не удалось прорваться, потому что система работает - не без огрех, ложных срабатываний и прочих недостатков, но работает. Нужно не прорываться, а остановиться, задать себе вопрос - "может быть я делаю что-то не так?" - и попробовать найти другой вариант действий, который приведет к другому, "более лучшему" результату.

Comment: @insolor, вы правы, если одной из целей сайта является подобный отбор его участников. Вероятно в этом есть здравый смысл

Comment: @avp, это не цель самого сайта, но это цель "системы саморегуляции" - отсеивать некачественные вопросы (не участников). Дальше (вследствие встреченного противодействия) участник скорее всего уйдет, но возможно позже поймет, что он делал что-то не так, и вернется.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте не будем нагнетать. Тот "конкурс" – очевидно [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) и сделан только в целях "демонстрации проблемы". И никак не помогает ее решить. Я буду рад в этом ошибиться, но сильно сомневаюсь, что это не так.

Проблема с "конкурсами" будет решаться. Надеюсь, что менее радикальными способами, чем было недавно продемонстрировано.

Давайте не будем терзать и пробовать границы [и без того шатких и монструозных] правил, просто чтобы попробовать и чтобы высказать свое "фе".

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, [вот этот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11164/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-c?noredirect=1#comment47454_11164) мой комментарий.

Comment: Призыв не нагнетать, это правильно, но боюсь, он не подействует на противников конкурсов и прочих закрывашек. Все равно будут закрывать, вызывая негативные настроения у сторонников свободы

Answer (score 1):

Он закрыт как дубликат, причём самим автором вопроса. Так что все вопросы про закрытие к нему...

PS: А теперь его с другим вопросом слили, хотя и как-то кривовато...

Comment: А можете поправить, чтобы этот основным был: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212383/1365 ? А то сейчас все слито на удаленный вопрос.