# Вопрос, соответствующий тематике Меты, заблокирован как «не соответствует тематике»

Tags: обсуждение, мета, заблокированные-вопросы, модераторский-произвол

Вопрос [«Сообщество уже больше полугода поддерживает откровенный оффтопик. Доколе?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370) имеет прямое отношение к тематике Меты, так как поднимает проблему нарушения правил на Stack Overflow.

Более того, эта проблема до сих пор не решена (уже сильно больше полугода, ага).

Однако сейчас на нём висит блокировка с подписью:

> Этот вопрос и ответы на него заблокированы, так как он не соответствует тематике сайта [...]

Ну что за произвол опять?

Снимите несправедливую блокировку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121177/discussion-between-nikolaj-sarry-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 4):

Андрей, а может быть уже достаточно? Отличное дружное сообщество, отличные вопросы, отличные ответы. Что еще надо? В вашем вопросе осталось всего лишь только три вопроса (прошу прощения за тавтологию), и все три - это новогодняя тематика. И как показывает их очень высокий рейтинг, сообществу нужны такие вопросы. Свои же вопросы я отредактировал, исключительно только ради уважения к вам и другим участникам, которые придерживаются ваших взглядов. И заметьте, вы мои вопросы вычеркнули из своего списка, но один из них так и остается закрытым. Почему же вы его не переоткрываете, если не считаете оффтопиком? Вот у меня такой возможности нет, чтобы голосовать за его переоткрытие. А еще вы говорите о несправедливости...

По существу. Как мне кажется, ваша тема про оффтопики исчерпала себя целиком и полностью, причем уже давно. Она потеряла свою надобность, свою значимость и актуальность. Она стала не интересна сообществу, и является уже раздражителем для сообщества. Она всех уже просто задолбала. Более того, я считаю, что подобные темы вносят только раскол в сообщество, и это недопустимо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122742/discussion-on-answer-by-sevastopol-----).

Comment: Первый абзац опустим (он не по теме, да еще и на личности переходит), по второму: исчерпание темы - это не повод для блокировки. Блокировка это как раз наоборот - силовое решение с посылом "мало ли что вы хотите, мы не дадим вам высказываться по этой теме".

Answer (score 2):

Я не так давно на мете *(около полугода)*, но с интересом наблюдаю за ситуацией, к которой относится вопрос [«Сообщество уже больше полугода поддерживает откровенный оффтопик. Доколе?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370).

Я понимаю, о чём говорит andreymal и понимаю, о чём говорят его основные "идеологические" противники: Sevastopol' и Victor VosMottor *(извините за имена, но я думаю, что это и так все видят)*.

#### Я вижу проблему в том, что кто-то не понимает целей сообщества.

**Надо начать именно с этого.**

*Какая цель, допустим, у системы образования? Цель системы образования - выпускать образованных людей, которые будут эффективно работать. Какая цель у полиции? Цель полиции - безопасное общество, лишённое преступности.*

#### Что такое StackOverflow? Зачем существует этот сайт и какая цель у его сообщества?

Я обращаюсь к странице [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), где написано следующее:

> Этот сайт посвящён исключительно получению ответов. Это не форум для
> дискуссий. Здесь не место пустым разговорам.

Я приведу ещё цитату с той же страницы:

> Спрашивайте о **реальной** проблеме, с которой вы столкнулись. Опишите в
> деталях, что вы делаете и чего хотите добиться.

А вот цитата со страницы [«На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Формат сайта подразумевает общение в виде вопросов и ответов на них и,
> хотя программисты любят поговорить о чем угодно, всё-таки некоторые
> вопросы не приветствуются, даже если они и принадлежат указанной выше
> тематике.

Однако всё это скорее правила, дополнения. Здесь не идёт речи о непосредственной цели StackOverflow. После некоторых поисков я нашёл то, что искал. Вот что я нашёл на странице [«Манифест сообщества»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto):

> ## Миссия
>
> Общими силами создать библиотеку подробных ответов на все
> прикладные вопросы по программированию.

и, наконец:

> ## Цель
>
> Создать мир, в котором на каждый запрос к поисковику, в выдаче
> есть ссылка на развёрнутый ответ на русском языке.

Теперь я обращусь к высказанной andreymal проблеме конкурсов. Нам надо просто посмотреть, соответствуют ли развлекательные конкурсы цели и миссии сообщества. Например, можно рассмотреть вопрос [«Новогодний конкурс 2021 года!»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1225740/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-2021-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Давайте посмотрим, отвечает ли этот вопрос требованиям, указанным в манифесте и цели сообщества?

Моё мнение: нет

Миссия сообщества заключается в том, чтобы создать библиотеку **прикладных** ответов и вопросов, то есть ответов и вопросов, имеющих чисто практическое значение. Я очень сомневаюсь, что хоть кому-то принесёт пользу ответ о том, как рисовать новогоднюю ёлку средствами CSS.

Что касается цели, то этот конкурсный вопрос ни на йоту не приближает нас к её достижению. Никто не будет искать, как сделать ту же ёлку при помощи CSS. К тому же в такой расплывчатой формулировке, какая присутствует в вопросе.

> ## Ну в конце концов участвовать в таких конкурсах просто весело!

Да, весело. Но я знаю вот что: ни одна группа людей и ни одно сообщество ни разу в истории не добивались успеха, если со всей возможной жёсткостью не придерживались своих же правил.

Скажите, весело ли будет учителю если он пойдёт пить чай в учительскую во время урока? Да, уж всяко веселей, чем учить детей. А весело ли будет полицейскому, если он будет брать взятки? Уж точно веселей, чем жить на одну зарплату!

Наше общество не находится в хорошем состоянии. В частности, потому что политики, полицейские и учителя ведут себя так, чтобы им "было весело", вместо того, чтобы просто выполнять свою работу.

Да, я утрирую. Но я просто указываю на то, к чему скатится наше сообщество, если мы будем отклоняться от жёстких правил.

Да, нам будет весело. Но базу знаний мы никогда не построим.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122743/discussion-on-answer-by-zhenyria-----).