# Вопрос, не являющийся дубликатом, закрыт как дубликат

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты, модераторский-произвол

Есть два **абсолютно разных** вопроса:

- [вопрос про оффтопик на основном сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370);
- [вопрос про несправедливые блокировки на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11435).

По какой такой волшебной логике второй вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом первого?

Теперь к требованию снять несправедливую блокировку добавляется требование снять несправедливый дубликат.

---

Все требования всё ещё актуальны.

Comment: *`"Интересно, будет ли новому владельцу SO ..."`* -- закроют весь ruSO, чтобы не мешались под ногами

Comment: вангую закрытие этого вопроса как дубликата

Comment: Блокировать обсуждения онтопика на мете - это так себе решение. Вы ж выбрали новых модераторов, зовите их, пусть снимают блокировку. или хоть как-то ее обоснуют. Ну а если выбрали таких модераторов - то сами себе злобные буратины.

Comment: @PashaPash это ложная аргументация на многих уровнях )

Answer (score -1):

**Первый вопрос** ([Сообщество уже больше полугода поддерживает откровенный оффтопик. Доколе?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370)) заблокирован с причиной:

> Этот вопрос и ответы на него заблокированы, так как он **не соответствует тематике сайта**, но имеет историческое значение. Для него недоступна публикация ответов и другие действия.
> *// добавлено выделение жирным*

Вопрос более чем соответствует тематике Меты <s>и должен быть открыт. Да, модераторам придется постараться и поподдерживать порядок в обсуждениях и комментариях, а как иначе, они же не только за ромбом баллотировались.</s> В ходе обсуждения, выяснилось, что по вопросу принято решение. Было бы хорошо это решение отразить более четко и явно. (спасибо @NicolasChabanovsky за уточнение). Итого, следует более явно отразить резолюцию и отредактировать причины блокирования.

---

**Второй вопрос** ([Вопрос, соответствующий тематике Меты, заблокирован как «не соответствует тематике»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11435)) заблокирован с причиной:

> **На этот вопрос уже даны ответы** здесь:
> [Сообщество уже больше полугода поддерживает откровенный оффтопик. Доколе?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370) (8 ответов)
> *// добавлено выделение жирным*

Данная причина так же "выдуманная". Видимо закрывающий поленился прочесть вопрос и понять, что первый вопрос сводится к *"Почему ruSO поддерживает оффтопик?"*, а этот - к *"Почему вопрос по теме закрыт?"*, и, вместо того, чтобы вопрос решить, или, хотя бы, скорректировать, просто закрыл.

---

Итого, мы видим два вопроса закрытых по необоснованным причинам.

Вот говорят, *"вопросы закрыты согласно духу закона"*, *"подобные вопросы плодятся"* - за этим чувствуется некоторая неприязнь к теме именно первого вопроса и рассмотрение последующих вопросов как продолжений *неприятной* темы. Тем не менее, вопросы вполне самостоятельные (см. краткое изложение выше), а дух какого именно "закона" нарушен - так и не сформулировано.

Для Базы Знаний (Меты) оба вопроса вполне самодостаточны, а их авторство и не важно. Так их рассматривать и следует. Вынужден присоединиться к требованиям ТС - "снять несправедливую блокировку" и "снять несправедливый дубликат". Проблемы надо обсуждать (в нашем случае, в соответствующих вопросах), а не блокировать в ключе "".

---

Update 1 (11/06): Написал вопрос на MSE - [What is the course of actions when elected moderators lock and close questions with unjustified reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366397)

Update 2 (11/06): Вопрос на MSE закрыт как дубликат (справедливо). Отправил информацию через "Связаться с нами". Посмотрим что будет ..

Update 3 (21/06): Написал Nicolas Chabanovsky в чат (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58397730#58397730) по поводу обращения через "Связаться с нами". Чат не-приватный, кто хочет - может ознакомиться.

Comment: Модераторы минусуют)

Comment: Так я только "за"! Но пускай скажут, чем именно мой ответ "не является полезным. Пусть предложат свой, более полезный.

Comment: Минус от меня. о "Связаться с нами" говорили уже не раз и не в одной теме. По поводу конкретных вопросов, я с вами  не согласен, ибо, на мой личный взгляд, вопросы закрыты согласно "духу закона". Это не всегда работает и с этим не всегда стоит соглашаться, но в этом случае мне такое решение понятно и близко.

Comment: @AntonMenshov спaсибо за комментарий! Про "связаться с нами" результатов не видел, пробую ). Про "дух закона" - не вижу, как он тут применим, да и дух какого именно закона? Да даже если и так - следовало явно указать причины "вот закон, вот его дух", а не закрывать "абы чем". Это касается обоих закрытых вопросов. Вы пишете "вопросы закрыты согласно духу" - все же стоит абстрагироваться от темы первого вопроса и рассматривать последующие как самостоятельные, а не как "продолжение". Напомню, что для Базы Знаний вопросы самодостаточны, а их авторство не важно. Так их рассматривать и следует.

Comment: Если бы вопрос оставался один, и участник боролся за его переоткрытие, то возможно и стоило бы поднимать тему "а-ля несправедливости". Но так как подобные вопросы плодятся, то это похоже уже на СПАМ. Модераторам следует полностью удалить весь этот спам, а участника заблокировать.

Comment: @Sevastopol' приведите пожалуйста список "подобных вопросов"

Comment: @Kromster "База знаний" применима для основного сайта. Для меты — я бы не стал применять эту аналогию. Указывать о духе закона (и то есть мое ощущение, которое может не совпадать ни с чьим) могу я, — а если бы я был модератором, я бы предпочел не указывать это напрямую, ибо это просто означает подставиться под удар определенной группы людей, у которых будет сильный упор на "букву правил".

Comment: @AntonMenshov Мета это тоже База Знаний, только иной тематики (о самом ruSO, а не о программировании и сис.администрировании). Поэтому тут и дубликатами вопросы закрываются, и всячески рекомендуется вопросы задавать "в общем о ситуациях", а не "о конкретных" вещах. Мне кажется, это очень плохо, когда считается уместным скрывать свои мотивы при принятии решений влияющих на сообщество и избегать обсуждений. Скажите, а под какой удар вы боитесь подставится, получить 2-3 минуса на Мете, или проявить свой характер и недополучить 3-5 голосов на следующих выборах мод.состава? не понимаю вас

Comment: @Kromster смотрите, я с удовольствием объясняю свою позицию и обсуждаю проблемы, в том числе сообщества в целом. Но до той поры, пока это не переходит в "спам" и замыливание вопроса. После этого, остается только спорить об одном и том же. В данном случае, я конкретно это и вижу.

Comment: Я предпочитаю тратить свое время эффективно. В этом и "подстава". Голоса меня вообще давно не волнуют.

Comment: @AntonMenshov разумно. Однако "замыливание" вопроса касается только самого вопроса. По нему вполне достаточно поставить плюс/минус и пойти дальше. Здесь же почему-то члены сообщества ставят знак "следует из" там, где никакого следования нет. Из вопроса "про соревнования", не следует, что "вопрос про закрытие" относится к соревнованиям, и далее не следует, что "вопрос ошибочно закрыт как дубликат" относится к ним же. Как бы нам эту ложную цепь разрубить?

Comment: Я не уверен, что конкретно эту ложную цепь стоит разрубать. Сообщество (активное на мете) голосами довольно четко показывает, что конкретно эта проблема не входит в число приоритетных.

Comment: @AntonMenshov какая именно из проблем? ) Соревнования? Необоснованные закрытия? Ложные дубликаты? Вопросы обращающие внимание на это? )) То что, плюсы/минусы поставили - к этому претензий то нет. Претензии то к действиям мод.состава. Сегодня им "это" не нравится, завтра "то", послезавтра они будут все "неприоритетное" закрывать не удосуживаясь следованию правилам и даче обоснований. Такое себе .. )

Comment: @Kromster, `приведите пожалуйста список "подобных вопросов"` - список в правой колонке и в теле вопроса

Comment: @Sevastopol' перечитайте пожалуйста комментарии выше, хотя вопросы и могут казаться "подобными" - это ложное впечатление. Колбаса не подобна пачке кофе или кружке или подарочной карте, только потому что вам их один и тот же кассир пробивает в магазине.

Comment: @Kromster, нечему тут казаться. СПАМ он и есть СПАМ. Который необходимо удалить, а участника заблокировать.

Comment: @Sevastopol' если вы считаете, что вопросы (или ответы) спам (то есть рекламные), то стоит их отмечать соответствующей тревогой. Но я прочитал оба вопроса, и никакой рекламы в них не увидел. Я увидел лишь то, что первый вопрос залочен с несоответствующей причиной, а второй закрыт с несоответствующей причиной.

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky в том чате предпочёл проигнорировать, что правила проведения соревнований на практике не работают, решения по-прежнему нет.

Comment: @andreymal не стоит вот так разбрасываться обвинениями. Давайте это обсудим в чате?

Comment: @Kromster это уже многократно обсуждалось прямо здесь на Мете, но Николай очень старательно избегает какой-либо конкретики